# Can I raise the volume of the radio music?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

This is sort of a two part question, so bear with me. I've got Radio volume turned up all the way in the settings, but the music playing over the Mojave Music and New Vegas radio stations is still pretty quiet. In glaring contrast, Mr. New Vegas himself (you look beautiful today, by the way) is very loud.

Can I raise the music volume in any way, without blasting my ears out with Mr. New Vegas in between songs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the Mojave Music radio station doesn't have a host to blast your ears, it'd be a shame to have to limit your listening options to just that station. It seems that there are two ways to fix this. The best way, in my opinion, is to [utilize a game mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/43720) which does the work for you. If you're the do-it-yourself type or if the mod doesn't do what you want, you may have to get yourself a [sound file editor and increase the volume](https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/dvyq5/if_you_think_the_radio_in_fallout_new_vegas_is/) of the tracks by hand. Outside of those options, there are plenty more radio mods which [add new stations](https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/categories/88/) with more music tracks. Good luck!